# How to check if a mdb file has password?

Tags: c#, ms-access, passwords

I use this method to set password for .mdb file:

```
    private static bool SetPassword(string filePath, string newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                string OledbConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Mode=12;", filePath);

                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(OledbConnectionString))
                {
                    string sql = string.Empty;
                    sql = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD [{0}]", newPassword);
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonLogUtility.GetLogger(LoggerType.Other).Error(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But I want to check if the .mdb file is already password protected, so that I need not set password every time I run my application. Also when I already set a password from null to a string, next time I run my application, it will throw exception in method SetPassword().
So I want to check if .mdb file has password each time I run the SetPassword() method, how can I do this?

Comment: I think if you try to access a password-protected database without providing user/password in the connection string, it will throw an exception. So you could perhaps try to connect to the database without a user/pass, and if it fails, try to connect with your user/pass instead (whereas if you can connect without user/pass then just set the password).

Comment: Or I can call this method when .mdb file isn't password protected and if the file is password protect I won't call this method.

Comment: Yes, either way would work fine.

Comment: How to check if the file is password protected is just what I confuse point. And how can I avoid throwing exception.